# Three column in Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

i have this listview with news...
But each new news is in the new row...
I need 3 news in each row...

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="NovinkaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Novinka") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="NovinkaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Novinka") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>                     
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

This listview write each new into next row...but i need THREE news into ONE ROW.
It is possible?

Comment: Maybe change your datasource to group every 3 entries/entities together ?

Comment: Have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.grouptemplate.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try likes this !

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <table>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="NovinkaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Novinka") %>' />
                </td>
        </table>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="NovinkaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Novinka") %>' />
                </td>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" runat="server">
            <tr>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>                     
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

### or

Change your `listView` to `datalist` , reference [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) . It's what you need !
In a simple way ,

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"  RepeatColumns="3"   
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="NovinkaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Novinka") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Your `AlternatingItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` are the same ! I think you can remove  `AlternatingItemTemplate` , isn't it ?

Comment: I dont know What do you mean...:/